# iOS – Deallocation issue when switching UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwindow

I use to contextually switch key `UIWindow`s in my app to provide a bit cleaner flow – Welcome window => Main screen with items list <=> Item container with burger menu and stuff.

Example function follows:

```c
- (void)updateKeyWindow:(UIWindow *)window withTransition:(WindowTransition)transition
{
    UIWindow *originalWindow = _keyWindow;
    _keyWindow = window;

    window.alpha = 0;
    [originalWindow resignKeyWindow];
    [originalWindow resignFirstResponder];
    originalWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    window.transform = (transition == WindowTransitionFlyDown) ? CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.02, 1.02) :
                       (transition == WindowTransitionFlyUp)   ? CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.96, .96) :
                                                                 CGAffineTransformIdentity;

//  [UIView animateWithDuration:.24 animations:^{

        window.alpha = 1;
        originalWindow.alpha = 0;
        window.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        originalWindow.transform = (transition == WindowTransitionFlyDown) ? CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.96, .96) :
                                   (transition == WindowTransitionFlyUp)   ? CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.02, 1.02) :
                                                                             CGAffineTransformIdentity;

//  } completion:^(BOOL b){

        [originalWindow resignFirstResponder];
        [originalWindow removeFromSuperview];
        [originalWindow.rootViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        originalWindow.rootViewController = nil;
        originalWindow = nil;

//  }];
}
```

I use animations to provide nice transitions, but I've commented it out to test if it's not the cause of the issue I have.

The thing is, after dropping `originalWindow` from the hierarchy and quitting the block/function, the `UIWindow` **is NOT being released** and hangs *somewhere* in the space. I've tested this with child class by putting breakpoint inside overloaded `-dealloc`.

I've checked both `UIApplication`'s `-keyWindow` and `AppDelegate`'s `-window`, both having new `UIWindow` object assigned.

However after tapping *anywhere* on the screen, the `-dealloc` for the previous `UIWindow` is triggered with some `-[UITouch dealloc]` stuff in the call stack.

[image: Call stack after tapping inside new UIWindow triggering dealloc of old UIWindow]

I find this behaviour completely weird, there must be something wrong within the `UIKit`, I'm not expecting there's anything wrong on my side with this approach.

Comment: Did you figure out what is the reason for such behaviour and how to avoid it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not yet. Even when experimenting around a minimal example, this behaviour still occurs.

Comment: Was there any solution for this? Issue still actual after 6 years...

Comment: I don't really have any quick project to test it on today, but if you still reproduce the issue, the Memory Debugger in Xcode is there to help, unlike couple of years back. 

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [the `resignKeyWindow` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWindow/resignKeyWindow):

> Never call this method directly. The system calls this method and posts UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification to let the window know when it is no longer key...

Try removing that and seeing if it fixes the crash.

Comment: You're right, it's proper not to call it. With or without, still no effect. It doesn't crash, but the window keeps retained (not being deallocated as I expect when dropping all references) until user touch event. That's the point of the question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is UIApplication's keyWindow is weak by definition. So you should have to connect your UIWindow's strongly on some object; like ApplicationDelegate or some singleton.